# Linear Regression And Coding

Tags: statistics

I'm revising for my A-level Statistics exam and need to figure out where / when coding has an effect.

What I'm currently stuck on is the effect coding has on values for $Sxy$ where $x= y \;$or$\;x $.

How, if it, does coding affect the value of $Sxy$; I've been told there's a square relationship; however, I recall there being no effect.

** If anyone is familiar with the Edexcel A-level Curriculum where are the key places coding has an effect.

Comment: I am not sure what "$x= y \;$or$\;x $" is supposed to mean.  But the variance and covariance will not be affected by subtracting a constant from each data value, while they will be affected by dividing by a constant.  The sum of products is likely to be affected in either case.  If the same coding is applied to $x$ and $y$ values, the slope of the regression line should not change

Comment: $x=y$ or $x$ means $x = y$ or $x$ - As in $Sxy = Syy$ or $Sxy$